# how to remove duplicates in arrayList of Employee based on ename

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, duplicates

how to remove duplicates in arrayList of Employee based on ename
below is the code.

```
package collection;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Employee extends ArrayList<Employee> {

    int empno;
    String ename;

    public boolean add(Employee e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Employee e1=(Employee)e;
        if(e1.getEname().equals(this.getEname()))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return super.add(e);
    }

    public int getEmpno() {
        return empno;
    }
    /*public void setEmpno(int empno) {
        this.empno = empno;
    }
    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }*/

    public String getEname() {
        return ename;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [empno=" + empno + ", ename=" + ename + "]";
    }

    public Employee(int empno, String ename) {
        super();
        this.empno = empno;
        this.ename = ename;
    }



}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make much sense. Why is an employee also a List of Employees (which then are all Lists of Employees, etc.etc.)?

Comment: `if(employeeArrayList.contains(ename))  //do stuff`

Comment: kk i forgot to remove that do you have any idea

Comment: Why don't you use Set?

Comment: use a HashSet instead of an ArrayList

Comment: i know set does not allow duplicates but This is interview question

Answer (score 1):

The `extends ArrayList<Employee>` is copy and paste error? If you remove that you can use just put all the employees in a [`java.util.Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) - which doesn't allow duplicates by definition.

The Java 8 syntax is:

```
Set<Employee> employeeSet = new TreeSet<>((e1, e2) 
   -> e1.getEname().compareTo(e2.getEname());
employeeSet.addAll(originalEmployeeList);
List<Employee> noDuplicatesEmployeeList = new ArrayList<>(employeeSet);
```

Make sure that `getEname()` doesn't return `null`.

If you are not allowed to use any collection except for lists, you have to use a nested iteration to remove duplicates. This runs in [image: O(n^2)].

```
for (Employee e1 : l) {
  for (Iterator<Employee > i = l.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    Employee e2 = i.next();
    if (e1 != e2 && e1.getEname().equals(e2.getEname())) {
      i.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

Or - if you are allowed to reorder - you can sort the list and remove duplicates in one more iteration. This runs in [image: O(n*log(n)))].

```
l.sort((e1, e2) -> e1.getEname().compareTo(e2.getEname());
String cmpEname = null;
for (Iterator<String> i = l.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
   Employee e = i.next();
   if (e.getEname().equals(cmpEname)) {
     i.remove();
   } else {
     cmpEname = e.getEname();
   }
 }
```

Also, note that your questions was how to **remove duplicates** which is different from creating a list that doesn't allow duplicates. You should discuss the benefits of each approach with your interviewer.

Comment: can we override the add method???? i don't want to use any other kind of collection...

Comment: @manishankarsirisipalli you can create your own class that composes an ArrayList and make your own add list that checks if the object is in the list first. Why don't you want to use another collection?.

Answer (score 0):

Using TreeSet is the best approach, but you may also design your own class that wrapped the list and add your own functionality if you are absolutely limited to ArrayList. Now just add the employees to your new array.

```
 public class MyArray{

   ArrayList<Employee> list;

   public MyArray(){
         list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
   }

   ....just copy all the same functions like
   public add(Employee e){
         list.add(a);
   }
   .....

   public void add(Employee e){
         if(!list.contains(e)) list.add(e);
   }

}
```